# Recursion on list of pairs in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I have tried many times but I still stuck in this problem, here is my input:

```
 (define *graph*
  '((a . 2) (b . 2) (c . 1) (e . 1) (f . 1)))
```

and I want the output to be like this: ((2 a b) (1 c e f))

Here is my code:

```
(define group-by-degree
  (lambda (out-degree)
    (if (null? (car (cdr out-degree)))
        'done
        (if (equal? (cdr (car out-degree)) (cdr (car (cdr out-degree))))
            (list (cdr (car out-degree)) (append (car (car out-degree))))
            (group-by-degree (cdr out-degree))))))
```

Can you please show me what I have done wrong cos the output of my code is (2 a). Then I think the idea of my code is correct.

Please help!!!

Comment: The general idea of the solution is not correct. You're not keeping track of the elements that have been encountered, for that you need an  additional data structure. In my solution I show how to do this with a hash table.

Comment: And just one more thing, I think that the answer of Zack Stack will be correct if i filter the list firstly by the second element of pairs, then apply his algorithm and finally append 2 lists together. What do you think about my idea? I'm trying it to see what happens :)

Comment: I think it might work if you sort the list first, using the second element of each pair for ordering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very nice and elegant way to solve this problem, would be to use hash tables to keep track of the pairs found in the list. In this way we only need a single pass over the input list:

```
(define (group-by-degree lst)
  (hash->list
   (foldl (lambda (key ht)
            (hash-update
             ht
             (cdr key)
             (lambda (x) (cons (car key) x))
             '()))
          '#hash()
          lst)))
```

The result will appear in a different order than the one shown in the question, but nevertheless it's correct:

```
(group-by-degree *graph*)
=> '((1 f e c) (2 b a))
```

If the order in the output list is a problem try this instead, it's less efficient than the previous answer, but the output will be identical to the one in the question:

```
(define (group-by-degree lst)
  (reverse
   (hash->list
    (foldr (lambda (key ht)
             (hash-update
              ht
              (cdr key)
              (lambda (x) (cons (car key) x))
              '()))
           '#hash()
           lst))))

(group-by-degree *graph*)
=> '((2 a b) (1 c e f))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why the lambda is necessary; you can directly define a function with 
`(define (function arg1 arg2 ...) ...)`
That aside, however, to put it briefly, the problen is that the cars and cdrs are messed up. I couldn't find a way to tweak your solution to work, but here is a working implementation:

```
; appends first element of pair into a sublist whose first element 
; matches the second of the pair
(define (my-append new lst) ; new is a pair
  (if (null? lst)
    (list (list (cdr new) (car new)))

    (if (equal? (car (car lst)) (cdr new))
      (list (append (car lst) (list (car new))))
      (append (list (car lst)) (my-append new (cdr lst)))
    )
  )
)

; parses through a list of pairs and appends them into the list
; according to my-append
(define (my-combine ind)
  (if (null? ind)
    '()
    (my-append (car ind) (my-combine (cdr ind))))
)

; just a wrapper for my-combine, which evaluates the list backwards
; this sets the order right
(define (group-by-degree out-degree)
  (my-combine (reverse out-degree)))
```

Comment: This solution won't work if the input is not strictly sorted by the `cdr` part of the pairs, for instance it'll fail with this input: `'((d . 1) (a . 2) (b . 2) (c . 1) (e . 1) (f . 1))`